# Empty line at the end of the output

Tags: c++

So I have a "db.csv" data file. Code reads each value from the file separated by a comma (value1, ...). Unnecessary spacings from the lines are deleted, then the finished line is printed out as desired (one space between values). The problem is that I have to pass the tests on a site called repl.it. And I fail every test, because there is an extra blank line at the end of the output. Any suggestions? I know, that it's probably because of the endl at the cout, but how else do I do it?

Minimal reproducible code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    fstream file("db.csv", ios::in);
    string value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, line;

    cout << "result:" << endl;

    while (getline(file, line)) {
        if (line.length() > 1) {
            istringstream str1(line);

            while (getline(str1, value1, ','),
                   getline(str1, value2, ','),
                   getline(str1, value3, ','),
                   getline(str1, value4, ','),
                   getline(str1, value5, '\n')) {
                value1.erase(remove(value1.begin(), value1.end(), ' '), value1.end());
                value2.erase(remove(value2.begin(), value2.end(), ' '), value2.end());
                value3.erase(remove(value3.begin(), value3.end(), ' '), value3.end());
                value4.erase(remove(value4.begin(), value4.end(), ' '), value4.end());
                value5.erase(remove(value5.begin(), value5.end(), ' '), value5.end());

                cout << value1 << " " << value2 << " " 
                     << value3 << " " << value4 << " " 
                     << value5 
                     << endl;
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

db.csv file data:

```
Riga,Kraslava,Pr,15:00,11.00

Riga ,Kraslava,Pr ,18:00,11.00
   Kraslava,Riga,Pr,08:00,11.00
Kraslava,Daugavpils,Ot ,10:00, 3.00
Ventsplis,8.00,Liepaja,Sv,20:00
Dagda,Sv

Rezekne,Riga,Tr,13:00,10.50
Dagda,Kraslava,  Ce,18:00,  2.50
Dagda,Kraslava,Ce,18:00,2.50,Sv
  Riga,Ventspils,  Pt,09:00  ,  6.70

Liepaja,Ventspils,Pt,17:00,5.50
```

Output:

```
Riga Kraslava Pr 15:00 11.00
Riga Kraslava Pr 18:00 11.00
Kraslava Riga Pr 08:00 11.00
Kraslava Daugavpils Ot 10:00 3.00
Ventsplis 8.00 Liepaja Sv 20:00
Rezekne Riga Tr 13:00 10.50
Dagda Kraslava Ce 18:00 2.50
Dagda Kraslava Ce 18:00 2.50,Sv
Riga Ventspils Pt 09:00 6.70
Liepaja Ventspils Pt 17:00 5.50
*blank line*
```

Desired output:

```
Riga Kraslava Pr 15:00 11.00
Riga Kraslava Pr 18:00 11.00
Kraslava Riga Pr 08:00 11.00
Kraslava Daugavpils Ot 10:00 3.00
Ventsplis 8.00 Liepaja Sv 20:00
Rezekne Riga Tr 13:00 10.50
Dagda Kraslava Ce 18:00 2.50
Dagda Kraslava Ce 18:00 2.50,Sv
Riga Ventspils Pt 09:00 6.70
Liepaja Ventspils Pt 17:00 5.50
```

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, line by line, what did your debugger show you what your program did, when the end of input is reached?

Comment: At the last iteration you don't need the `endl`

Comment: Oddly enough, I get the output you want when running that program with that input.

Comment: @TedLyngmo It might seem like it, but before the "path" (process 4128) exited with code 0. There is an empty line.

Comment: What "path" and process? I ran it on my computer and saw no path or process.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I mean the termination of the process. It prints the output, then there is the empty line and then there is the termination message.

Comment: That must be something special at that site. That's not how it looks when I run it - and the program exits normally. No strangeness. I would perhaps simplify it a bit and remove some code duplication. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/bPGb5T6fh)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thank you for the code simplify, but the empty line is on the visual studio output as well.

Comment: Print a line directly after the last line [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/fKxdG96f6). Is there a space between that line and the csv-output?

Comment: @TedLyngmo There is a space after the "----" line and the termination message, yes. This is in visual studio and the site I use for testing also.

Comment: Yeah, but what comes _after_ the "----" line is not from your program. You can't do anything about that.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Okey, thanks. I will ask about the problem to my professor, maybe the tests are just messed up.

Comment: `while (getline(file, line) && !line.empty())` will do.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Nope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix for this is adding

```
line.erase(remove(line.begin(), line.end(), '\r'), line.end());
```

to the code. But just to be sure (it probably is an overkill) I added this as I did with the spacing removal - this line for every value (value1, ..., value5). This fixed the issue right away. From what I understood from google, this prevents moving the cursor at the start of a new line.

Comment: Please do add an explanation along with your code for a more complete and detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than detect the last iteration and avoid putting a newline, it might be easier if you add the newline at the start of the loop and to avoid an extraneous newline at the start of the output, keep a Boolean variable `is_first` initially set to `true` and at the start of your loop body have

```
if (!is_first) 
    cout << endl;
is_first = false;
```

Ain’t pretty but it’s quick to code.

Comment: You mean "while (getline(file, line))" at the start of this while? If that, it didn't work either.

Comment: Yes, that is the loop I meant - What is incorrect about the output? Did you make sure to define ‘is_first’ before this loop?

Comment: Oh, I did not define it before the loop. Now I did, now it ads random spacings in between the lines, but seems like there is no blank line at the end anymore. From one problem into another I guess

Comment: Maybe it needs to be inside the if statement that checks how long the line is. Otherwise it’ll print a newline for every blank line in the input. Sorry I should have made these points clearer.

Comment: It's okey. This improved it, but still not quite fixed. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think this approach is cleaner:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

std::string filedata = R"(
Riga,Kraslava,Pr,15:00,11.00

Riga ,Kraslava,Pr ,18:00,11.00
   Kraslava,Riga,Pr,08:00,11.00
Kraslava,Daugavpils,Ot ,10:00, 3.00
Ventsplis,8.00,Liepaja,Sv,20:00
Dagda,Sv

Rezekne,Riga,Tr,13:00,10.50
Dagda,Kraslava,  Ce,18:00,  2.50
Dagda,Kraslava,Ce,18:00,2.50,Sv
  Riga,Ventspils,  Pt,09:00  ,  6.70

Liepaja,Ventspils,Pt,17:00,5.50

)";

std::string trim( const std::string& str ) {
    std::size_t pos = str.find_first_not_of( " \t" );
    if ( pos == std::string::npos ) return {};
    std::size_t last = str.find_last_not_of( " \t" );
    if ( last == std::string::npos ) return {};
    return str.substr( pos, last - pos + 1 );
}

std::vector<std::string> split( const std::string& line ) {
    std::size_t pos = 0;
    std::size_t next = 0;
    std::vector<std::string> fields;
    while ( next != std::string::npos ) {
        next = line.find_first_of( ',', pos );
        std::string field = next == std::string::npos ? line.substr(pos) : line.substr(pos,next-pos);
        fields.push_back( trim( field ) );
        pos = next + 1;
    }
    return fields;
}

int main() 
{
    istringstream file(filedata);
    cout << "result:" << endl;

    std::string line;
    while (getline(file, line)) {
        if (!line.empty()) {
            auto fields = split( line );
            for ( std::string field : fields ) {
                cout << field << ",";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Results in

```
result:
Riga,Kraslava,Pr,15:00,11.00,
Riga,Kraslava,Pr,18:00,11.00,
Kraslava,Riga,Pr,08:00,11.00,
Kraslava,Daugavpils,Ot,10:00,3.00,
Ventsplis,8.00,Liepaja,Sv,20:00,
Dagda,Sv,
Rezekne,Riga,Tr,13:00,10.50,
Dagda,Kraslava,Ce,18:00,2.50,
Dagda,Kraslava,Ce,18:00,2.50,Sv,
Riga,Ventspils,Pt,09:00,6.70,
Liepaja,Ventspils,Pt,17:00,5.50,
```

Compiler explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/enheGdjda

Comment: This does work, but there is a lot more to that code, this is only the minimal reproducible. I would still like to get some suggestions on how to edit the code I have to get the same results with not such a huge edit. Although, if nothing else comes up, I guess I will have to edit it your way.

Comment: Functions like split() and trim() are conspicuously missing from the C++ standard library. You should have them anyway. They are sorely necessary for dealing with strings.

Comment: @Jellyboy There is at least `std::views::split` since C++20

Comment: I know but I found the iterator pattern personally awkward to use. Most cases you really want to have all in one place, check the size, do some checking with random access.

Comment: Splitting a string into tokens/fields and store the results in a vector: All this is since years available in C++. It is always a one-liner. No need to create a function or write 10 lines of code. Since you are a very experienced software expert, you will find out soon. No offense intended. This is a free world. Everybody can do, what he wants, so please continue your way.